# Differential equation y' +mx^(-1)y=lnx where m is not -1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem. I need to solve for $y$ where

$$y' +\frac{m}{x}y=\ln(x)$$

where $m$ is constant, and there are 2 answers: where $m =-1$, and where $m \ne -1$.

I already got the answer for the first case:

$$y = cx + \frac{x}{2} \log^2(x)$$

but have no idea how to get the second one.

Does anyone have an idea of the direction to go in?
Thanks

Comment: Check my edit to make sure the problem is as you stated it (I wasn't sure what $m != -1$ meant, I thought you wanted $\ne$). Also, use an integrating factor to solve the problem, you can then solve for particular values of $m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y' + \frac mx y = ln x$

Multiply though by $x^m$

$x^my' + mx^{m-1} y = x^m ln x\\
\int x^my' + mx^{m-1} y = \int x^m ln x\\
x^my = \frac {x^{m+1}}{m+1} \ln x - \frac {x^{m+1}}{(m+1)^2}+ C\\
y =  \frac {x}{m+1} \ln x - \frac {x}{(m+1)^2} + Cx^{-m}$

if $m = -1$ we have something that is undefined.  Lets look more closely at this case.

$\frac{y}{x} - \frac {y'}{x^2} = \frac {\ln x}{x}\\
\frac{y}{x} = \frac 12 \ln^2 x + C\\
y = \frac 12 x\ln^2 x + Cx$

Comment: Let $u = \ln(x), du = 1/x dx$ $$\implies \int \ln(x)/x dx = \int u du = u^{2}/2 + C = (\ln(x))^{2}/2 + C$$..

Comment: Indeed, brain farts... thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for!